# Change color space to HSV or LAB or Pre process image before feeding it to neural network for training

Tags: python, image-processing, conv-neural-network, yolo, color-space

i want to train my neural network(YOLOv2) to differentiate between objects ob basis of color and some patterns in these objects. The contour of all objects is same(rectangular).

I have trained my dataset for 9 classes using YOLOv2 till 30000 steps and it works decent however, i have two objects which have the color white and light yellow. This is where i have a problem. The light yellow object is being recognised as white lots of times. These objects have not only different colors but also some special patterns on themm which differentiate them from each other. So in my opinion the color is playing a big role on the learning process of the neural network.

So i was thinking if i should change my colorspace from RGB to HSV or LAB and i am here looking for suggestions. Also my objects dont have just one color but multiple colors. So how do i set a multi color channel for HSV? Or LAB.

Do i just convert my training dataset to HSV or LAB and start training? Or should i make come changes in the YOLO neural network as well?

Any suggestion and reference to reading material is welcomed

Comment: HSV is more similar on how our brain works. But we cannot answer. You should test them. Note: we have colour adaptation, and we replace many time yellow with white. So you should be sure your images uses consistent white point, or machine could see what our brain is trained to actively correct out.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thank you for the reply. So what you suggest is that i convert the image to HSV color format then save it as jpeg or png file and then train and then check results,   am i right?

Comment: Maybe. You should try. It is difficult to forecast results, but if you have problem with yellow cast, I think HSV could really improve. Many models works with segmentation (and possibly starting with black and white, so the V of HSV). I would not work with jpg: compression artefacts. Is it tiff more efficient?

Comment: Oke thanks for the detailled  explanation. I will try to save it in .tiff and feed to YOLO